# Pyodbc Query w/ SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

I’ve been struggling to use `pyodbc` to execute a query:
• `cursor.execute({call my_query})`

The query for the Access database requires a connection to a SQL server. My current attempt involves creating two, separate connections: one for the Access database and another for the SQL server.

`cnxn1 = pyodbc.connect(‘DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver...`

`cnxn2 = pyodbc.connect(‘DRIVER={SQL Server}...`

I’m currently receiving the error

```
pyodbc.Error: (‘HY000’, ‘[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] ODBC—call failed. (-2001) (SQLExecDirectW)’)
```

I’d really appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Please provide more details. When exactly does the error occur? What's the query's SQL? Also, _The query for the Access database requires a connection to a SQL server_ sounds like nonsense to me, if Access requires a SQL server connection, it should be defined in the Access database or the query, not in Python

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#databases-containing-odbc-linked-tables) might help.